# bluebird + mongoose error: "Can't use $__ with Array."

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bluebird

I was trying to use bluebird + mongoose to query DevHiin instances for each Club respectively like the following code:

the data structure of DevHiin.clubs is:

```
  , clubs  : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Club' }]
```

and club_M is an instance of the Club schema:

```
  User.findOne({"_id": req.user._id})
    .populate('clubs', '-textIndex')
    .exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) res.status(500).json(err);

    if (user.clubs) {
      var clubs_M = user.clubs;


    for (c = 0; c < clubs_M.length; c++) {
        var club_M = clubs_M[c];

        if (club_M.lst > lstDate) {

          serverData.clubs.push(club_M);

          var ciinPromise = DevHiin.find({"clubs": {$elemMatch: club_M}, "ts": {"$gt": lastSyncTime}})
            .populate('uId', '_id username', null, null)        // get necessary user info for a hiin
            .lean()
            .sort("ts")
            .limit(10)
            .execAsync();
          promises.push(ciinPromise);
        }
      }

      Promise.all(promises).then(function (ciinArrays) {
        serverData.ciinArrays = ciinArrays;
        callback(ciinArrays);

      }).catch(function (err) {
        callback(err);
      });
```

unfortunately, I got the following error info:

```
"Error: Can't use $__ with Array.
at SchemaArray.castForQuery (/Users/vince-fan/WorkSpaces/MEAN/V_Starter/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/array.js:188:13)
at SchemaArray.cast$elemMatch (/Users/vince-fan/WorkSpaces/MEAN/V_Starter/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/array.js:336:23)
at SchemaArray.castForQuery (/Users/vince-fan/WorkSpaces/MEAN/V_Starter/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/array.js:191:19)
at module.exports (/Users/vince-fan/WorkSpaces/MEAN/V_Starter/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:196:39)
at Query.cast (/Users/vince-fan/WorkSpaces/MEAN/V_Starter/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2350:10)
at Query.find (/Users/vince-fan/WorkSpaces/MEAN/V_Starter/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:999:10)
at Query.exec (/Users/vince-fan/WorkSpaces/MEAN/V_Starter/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1984:17)
at Query.tryCatcher (/Users/vince-fan/WorkSpaces/MEAN/V_Starter/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:24:31)
at Query.ret [as execAsync] (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/vince-fan/WorkSpaces/MEAN/V_Starter/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promisify.js:1:0), <anonymous>:12:23)
at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/vince-fan/WorkSpaces/MEAN/V_Starter/controllers/sync.js:189:18)
at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/vince-fan/WorkSpaces/MEAN/V_Starter/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:175:45)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:169:7)
at Promise.safeEmit (/Users/vince-fan/WorkSpaces/MEAN/V_Starter/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:81:21)
at Promise.fulfill (/Users/vince-fan/WorkSpaces/MEAN/V_Starter/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:94:24)
at Promise.resolve (/Users/vince-fan/WorkSpaces/MEAN/V_Starter/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:113:23)
at /Users/vince-fan/WorkSpaces/MEAN/V_Starter/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1174:16
at /Users/vince-fan/WorkSpaces/MEAN/V_Starter/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:109:16
at doNTCallback0 (node.js:408:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:337:13)"
```

is this an bluebird promise error, or an mongoose error? how can I fix it?

Comment: Seems to me that one of your `club_M` instances (that you pass to `$elemMatch`) may be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

From the code it looks like you are trying to query using **[`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)** on an array value specified as the query criteria expression. I believe you need to use the **[`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** instead, this selects the documents where the value of the `clubs` field equals any value in the specified array, which is stored by the variable `club_M` in your case. Thus your query should look like this:

```
var ciinPromise = DevHiin.find({"clubs": {"$in": [club_M._id]}, "ts": {"$gt": lastSyncTime}})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually, clubs is an array of Club schema, and club_M is an instance of Club instance. I'm not sure if my query is right... I'm quite new in mongodb

Comment: @bolerovt I've updated my answer with a revised query since `clubs` is an array of `ObjectId`s and thus you could use that instead of the actual club object.

Comment: seems like, $in needs an array, should it be {$in: [club_M._id]} ?

Comment: or seems like $in is not necessary for querying an array field

Comment: @bolerovt You are right, you can either wrap the _id in an array (which wont be necessary) or query the club field directly with the `club_M._id` value.

Comment: still, thank you so much for your quick answer:), BTW, how can I "at_chridam", every time I tried to type it at the beginning of the line, it disappeared...

Comment: No worries. You can copy this text @chridam

Answer (score 0):

for querying field holds an array, simple treat it as normal field query.

My fixed code:

```
              var ciinPromise = DevHiin.find({"clubs": club_M._id, "ts": {"$gt": lastSyncTime}})
```